# docker buildkit not supported by daemon in AWS EKS kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, terraform, docker-buildkit

I am using Build Toolkit to build docker image for each microservice.

**./build.sh**

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
# ....
docker build -t ....
# ...
```

This works on my machine with docker (18.09.2).

However, it does not work with Jenkins, that I setup as following :

- EKS is provisioned with a Terraform module

  ```
  module "eks" {
    source   = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
    version  = "5.0.0"
    # ....
  }
  ```
- Jenkins is deployed on EKS (`v1.12.10-eks-ffbd9` , `docker://18.6.1`) via this [Helm Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins).
- Jenkins plugins as defined in Values of the helm release:

  - kubernetes:1.18.1
  - workflow-job:2.33
  - workflow-aggregator:2.6
  - credentials-binding:1.19
  - git:3.11.0
  - blueocean:1.19.0
  - bitbucket-oauth:0.9
- Jenkins Pipeline is declarative, and it uses a Pod template where the container image is `docker:18-dind` and the container name is `dind`.
- This is my Jenkinsfile

  ```
  pipeline {
    agent {
      kubernetes {
        defaultContainer 'jnlp'
        yamlFile 'jenkins-pod.yaml'
      }
    }
    stages {
      stage('Build Backends') {
        steps {
          container('dind') {
            sh 'chmod +x *sh'
            sh './build.sh -t=dev'
          }
          containerLog 'dind'
        }
      }
    }
  ```

  }

When Jenkins executes this pipeline, it shows this error :

```
buildkit not supported by daemon
```

I am not sure which software should I upgrade to make docker-buildkit work ? and to which version ?

- Terraform eks Module which is now 5.0.0 ?

Or

- docker:18-dind image which behaves like environment of the ephemeral Jenkins slaves ?

Or

- the Jenkins Plugin `kubernetes:1.18.1` ?

Comment: Can you try `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t ....` in your `./build.sh` ?

Answer (score 5):

As per [docker-ce sources](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/68852aa863516d5d3f2fc33f0a59e65d886a1671/components/cli/cli/command/image/build_session.go#L30), there are two requirements to make successful check `isSessionSupported` for starting `buildkit` session:

- `dockerCli.ServerInfo().HasExperimental`
- `versions.GreaterThanOrEqualTo(dockerCli.Client().ClientVersion(), "1.31"`

So:

- check version of your `docker-cli` library
- and is `HasExperimental` option enabled.

To check if it has Experimantal support, run:

`docker version -f '{{.Server.Experimental}}'`

Answer (score 2):

Docker buildkit support came out of experimental in 18.09, so you may need to upgrade docker inside of EKS:

> EKS (v1.12.10-eks-ffbd9 , docker://18.6.1

Or perhaps you have an old dind image (the `18-dind` should be new enough, but an older version of this tag pointing to 18.06 or 18.03 would not). You can try `18.09-dind` and `19-dind` which should both work if the build is actually happening inside dind.